# TcpClient not returning all lines read

Tags: c#, tcpclient

Was trying to get some text from a remote host with the `TcpClient` class.  Wanted to loop through the `stream.Read` until I get all the data.  If I use `bytesRead > 0` it just hangs.  If I run this code I only get the first line of output from the remote host and the program exits normally.  However, if I break on the first line in the do loop and step through each iteration manually in the debugger, I end up getting all the lines as I would have expected.  I don't really understand why this could be the case.  This is the code I was using:

```
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient("myserver.net", 1234);
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

            Byte[] buffer = new Byte[256];

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int bytesRead;
            do
            {
                bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                sb.Append(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead));
            } while (bytesRead == 256);
```

Just adding if I purposefully wait extra time each iteration it appears to get what I want, but I don't understand why this is happening...

```
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int bytesRead;
            do
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                sb.Append(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead));
            } while (bytesRead == 256);
```

Comment: `while (bytesRead == 256)` is probably what's wrong because a network stream may not send you all the data at once, it probably should be `while (bytesRead != 0)`, at least, although that's assuming the Read() blocks.

Comment: Also the sb.Append() may be buffering the data which would be why you don't see it. If it Read() blocks and never returns 0, then it will block forever unless the server closes the connection.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's working in the debugger is because you're slowing down the code enough to allow the network buffer to fill up. When you call `stream.Read` and pass in a length of 256 (`buffer.Length`), that just tells the stream to read whatever is in its buffer *up to that length*. If there are only 100 bytes in the buffer, it's only going to read 100 bytes and the return value will be 100. This is likely what's happening (the buffer doesn't have a full 256 bytes available), so your `while` condition is no longer satisfied and it's breaking the loop.

With that in mind, "all the data" is not something that you can guarantee without some kind of protocol in place. The stream itself could have data appear in its buffer (from your perspective) at any time. You either need to implement some kind of length specification (essentially giving your message a header structure, part of which describes how long the variable-length portion(s) of the message is/are) or some kind of reserved byte or byte sequence to serve as a terminator. Then you know either to read a particular number of bytes (and you don't exit until you do, unless you want to throw an exception) or you know to read until you encounter that terminator byte or byte sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `StreamReader` as said in comments...

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
client.Connect("myserver.net", 1234);

var stream = new StreamReader(client.GetStream(),Encoding.ASCII);
string line = null;
while ((line = stream.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Comment: This gives me all the lines I had expected, but it appears to block on the last line.  We never hit null and escape the loop.

Comment: @user17753 What do you get when other end closes the connection? I suspect that other end never closes the connection.

Comment: Yea, it must be staying open.

Comment: @user17753 Then how should the receiver end know when to exit the loop unless you send a special string such as `.<CRLF>` as SMTP do.

Comment: I'm looking for whatever the C#/.NET equivalent to the Winsock2/Win32 API for `WSAAsyncSelect` and `WM_SOCKET` message on a window procedure.  To, e.g., populate a textbox with whatever happens to stream in from the server.